# Wso2 Identity server Soap Remote user store management admin service throws access denied error

Tags: soapui, wso2, identity-management, wso2-identity-server

I have setup wso2 identity server with default h2 database configuration. when i tired to access its RemoteUserStoreManagerService.getTenantIdofUser() soap admin service with super tentant admin credentials 'admin/admin', its throws 'access denied' error.I found that error is raised because of 'super tenant' id is not set to zero(0). it has been set as '-1234' at backend. Kindly help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i know, `getTenantIdofUser` is a depreciated in WSO2 and it will not work properly.  Theoretically,  you can not retrieve the tenant id by providing the username. Because username is unique across tenants. There can be same username in two different tenant.  As you mentioned, there is some issue in the code as well. Super tenant id must be `-1234`.  However fixing this issue,  would not provide successful response from the `getTenantIdofUser` as it is already depreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.